# Trigger custom js script by using Magento observer

Tags: event-observer, javascript, script, action, magento-1.9.3.3

I need to trigger some custom js script in Magento for following actions,

1) customer account creation (customer_register_success)

2) Add to cart action (checkout_cart_product_add_after)

3) Remove a product from cart

4) Successful checkout

For now, I have created a module to observe customer_register_success and checkout_cart_product_add_after events and it is working as expected.

But, I am struggling to trigger the custom script on the particular event, please let me know suggestions to trigger the script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have managed to add js script for customer_register_success, checkout_cart_product_add_after and successful checkout. But I won't be able to add the script to remove the product from cart event!

Comment: Can anyone let me know valuable suggestions asap?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @MuthukumarSivasamy can you write your code here for customer_register_success ?